# Running command on starup AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run a command on the startup of the server. I tried to add the command to the User Data section:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user 
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot-1.14.4.jar
```

However that still didn't work, so I then in addition to the userdata, I added that same command to the rc.local file in /etc/:

```
touch /var/lock/subsys/local
cd /home/ec2-user
java -Xms1G -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -jar spigot-1.14.4.jar
```

However, that too doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing.

Also, the command I am running is meant to stay running until the server ends.

Answer (score 1):

UserData is only executed the first time the instance boots after it's created. Not upon subsequent reboots or shutdowns/starts.

Best to create a *systemd unit file* for your app and enable it. It can do some smarts like restarting the app if it fails, etc.

Have a look here for example: [**Creating and modifying systemd unit files**](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-managing_services_with_systemd-unit_files)

Hope that helps :)